# How to reuse a color from a cycle?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have two plot statements in a loop. I would like them both to use the same color from a color cycle and only increment the cycle once. The object is to have each curve and its regression line the same color and only step though the entire cycle once. How can I do so?

```
    colormap = plt.cm.hsv
    ax.set_prop_cycle('color', [colormap(i) for i in np.linspace(0.0, 0.9, self.numplots)])
    # plot the lines
    j = 0
    start = 40
    incrmnt = 10
    for line, rank in sortedSymbols:
        series = getattr(self, line)["CLOSE"]
        dates = pd.to_datetime(getattr(self, line)["DATE"]).dt.date
        name = self.symToNames[line]
        ax.plot(dates.iloc[-250:], series.iloc[-250:]/series.iloc[-250] * (start+j), label = name)
        y = series.iloc[-1]/series.iloc[-250] * (start+j)
        ax.annotate(name, xy=(1,y), xytext=(6,0), xycoords = ax.get_yaxis_transform(),
            textcoords="offset points", size=10, va="center")
        slope, intercept = np.polyfit(dates.iloc[-50:].index,
            series.iloc[-50:]/series.iloc[-250] * (start+j),1)
        ax.plot(dates.iloc[-50:], slope*dates.iloc[-50:].index+intercept)#, color = "gray")
        j += incrmnt
```

[image: Color cycle example]

Comment: You could have an array of colors (as strings) and set the color of each line

Comment: That thought gave me a solution. set_prop_cycle isn't useful in this context. Strip the list comprehension out like so: clr = [colormap(i) for i in np.linspace(0.0, 0.9, self.numplots)] Then iterate over clr like this: clr[i] Works perfectly.